# Getting the constrain error when an insertion fails

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I was playing with the media `ContentProvider` adding mp3 to it.

The code is something like this:

```
// LOOP1_PATH: /mnt/sdcard/60AH/hack043/loop1.mp3

ContentValues values = new ContentValues(5);
values.put(Media.ARTIST, "Android");
values.put(Media.ALBUM, "60AH");
values.put(Media.TITLE, "hack043");
values.put(Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
values.put(Media.DATA, LOOP1_PATH);

getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
```

If you run this code it works. If you try running it twice you will get the following stacktrace:

```
E/Database( 4102): Error inserting album_id=66 title=hack043 title_keyQQQQQ*Q*Q*Q mime_type=audio/mp3 date_added=1342706644 _display_name=loop12.mp3 sort_key=hack043 artist_id=133 _data=/mnt/sdcard/60AH/hack043/loop1.mp3
E/Database( 4102): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
E/Database( 4102):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
E/Database( 4102):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:61)
E/Database( 4102):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1582)
E/Database( 4102):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1426)
E/Database( 4102):  at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.insertInternal(MediaProvider.java:2166)
E/Database( 4102):  at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.insert(MediaProvider.java:1984)
E/Database( 4102):  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:206)
E/Database( 4102):  at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:146)
E/Database( 4102):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:320)
E/Database( 4102):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Not 100% sure, but I guess the constrain fails because the path is `UNIQUE`.

My question here is:

Is there a way to get more information about the constrain error?

Comment: API version is missing. Do you actually *need* more information? I mean you could always just query first and only insert if query comes back empty.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is a result of native function. Codes listed [here](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html) are translated to error messages.